# Built-in normalization attribute scikit-learn models for test data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

A lot of models from scikit-learn have a built-in normalization function, see for example the [API for ridge regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.predict). So when `normalize = True`, data is normalized when the function `.fit(X_train)` is called before the model is fitted to the data.

However, when calling the function `.predict()` for unseen test or validation data, the normalization mean and norm of the training data should be used in order to rescale the unseen data. Two questions:

- When using the function `.predict()`, is the unseen data also normalized before making predictions?
- If so, is this done using the normalization information from the training data only?

Comment: Please have a look at the [issue 4480](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4480). Apparently the scale and centring learnt during the fitting is used to correct the coef_ and intercept_ and then they are used for prediction, so actually, the data from training is used to normalize the prediction data. You can post a comment there if not clear on this.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that this would (should) be the case, still I find the API not clear about this. I'll add a comment.